# jQuery $.ajax only called when I break on it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm seeing an issue where my AJAX call is *only* happens if I break on it, and then move forward, in the Chrome dev tools.  That is, if I submit my form as a regular user would, the service is never hit.  If I set a breakpoint right on `$.ajax` and then simply F5 over it, the call is made.  Any ideas what would cause such behavior?

There are two textboxes (firstname and lastname) in a form (getUsername)

```
$('#getUsername').submit(function () {
    var firstname = $('#firstname').val(),
        lastname = $('#lastname').val();

    authenticationHelper.getUsername(firstname, lastname);
});
```

Then, the call is essentially like this, with a couple different doSomethings() in the same module (they don't do anything crazy)

```
authenticationHelper = function () {
    var getUsername = function (first, last) {
        var firstName = doSomething(first);
        var lastName = doSomething(last);

        doGetUsername(firstName, lastName);
    }

    var doSomething = function(string) {
        return string;
    }

    var doGetUsername = function (firstName, lastName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/api/user/',
            data: { first: firstName, last: lastName },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.log(xhr + status + err);
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        getUsername: getUsername
    }
}();
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: can you please provide a code example (js,html) to see your code in context.. thx

Comment: Have to see some code.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code, but I guess that you're calling it too soon in your page, make sure to call it only after your DOM is ready.

Comment: Ok, I've added the code.  The only reason I didn't originally was it doesn't tell you much without giving much more context, IMO.  @VictorEloy, the DOM is already loaded.

Comment: Additionally, even if I do break on the ajax call, neither success nor error are called (or complete, if I add that).

Comment: do you have the code html or js that triggers the AJAX request code you just posted?

Comment: Is the URL in the same domain as your page? If not, you should specify crossDomain: true for cross-domain requests...

Comment: Could you post the code that calls the AJAX?

Comment: Form is submitting, thus causing a postback, blocking that AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning false in your `submit` call, so `getUsername` is just getting submitted when you don't break before `authenticationHelper.getUsername` completes.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` would be better, of course. But yes, that is the problem.

Comment: Where should I be returning false?  in getUsername?

Comment: Inside the `submit` anonymous function. Alternatively, instead of `return false;`, you can do `event.preventDefault()`, as @lonesomeday pointed out.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed all the problems I was having (including error nor success being returned).